# Search and replace all cells with a certain value with openpyxl

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openpyxl

For my job I have large amount of excel files in which I have to replace certain values.
I just started with openpyxl and tried the following code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb1 = load_workbook(filename = 'testfile.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active


i = 0
for r in range(1,ws1.max_row+1):
    for c in range(1,ws1.max_column+1):
        s = ws1.cell(r,c).value
        if s != None or 'NM181841' in s: 
            ws1.cell(r,c).value = s.replace("hello","hi") 

            print("row {} col {} : {}".format(r,c,s))
            i += 1

wb.save('targetfile.xlsx')
print("{} cells updated".format(i))
```

On which I get following error "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable" this happends in line five: `if s != None or 'NM181841' in s:`

Does anyone have an idea what I did wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate through a type which is not iterable in the following:

```
or 'NM181841' in s:
```

What this line practically says is: "find 'NM181841' in 's'"  thus it would required to loop through 's' which is not possible since

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: I found the solution ```s = str(ws.cell(r,c).value)```

Comment: yes this would make `s` iterable

Comment: Why would it actualle make s iterable?

Answer (score 0):

I found my own mistake, instead of:
`s = ws1.cell(r,c).value`

I had to use

`s = str(ws1.cell(r,c).value)`

With the help of the @MwBakker